# C++ API design: is using void* a bad idea?

Tags: c++, c++11, api-design

I am working on an API that I want as generic as possible on the caller side. Main design idea is to provide a signal/slot sort of implementation that allows the user of the API to subscribe to a given set of events, and attach user-defined callbacks to them.

Public interface looks something like this:
`RetCallback subscribe(EventEnum& ev, std::function<void(void*)> fn) const;`
: note the `void(void*)` signature here. `EventEnum` is given in a public header file, as well as types definition.

Inner-works of the API would then notify its subscribed observers of the event through a notify method and provide data to forward to the client :

```
void dummyHeavyOperation() const {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    std::string data = "I am working very hard";
    notify(EventEnum::FooEvent, &data);
}
```

Client subscribes and casts data to (documented) type as follows:

```
auto subscriber = Controller->subscribe(EventEnum::FooEvent, callback);
```

where

```
void callback(void* data) {
    auto* myData = (std::string*) data;
    std::cout << "callback() with data=" << *myData << std::endl;

    /// Do things
}
```

Is this a reasonable design or is this frowned upon? What is your experienced modern C++ developer mind tells you?

[EDIT]
I should add as well that the API is delivered as a shared library loaded at run-time. So any compile time coupling (and code generation for that matter, unless I'm mistaken) is off the table

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want a `void*` if anyhow you cast it to a `std::string*`? Why not simply use a `std::string` ?

Comment: Because data type depends of the event. Sometimes it's a string, sometimes it's raw binary data that should be cast as a struct, and so on

Comment: there are several things that are worth raising an eyebrow imho. How can `subscribe` be `const`? Why is `EventEnum` passed as non-const ref? Why `void*` and not just `std::string`? Why are you using c-style cast?

Comment: the actual type of `data` depends on the `EventEnum` ?

Comment: If you can declare a base class for the pointer, even if it is not virtual, it helps document the interface. If the users are consistant as well, then they get a binding between the event sender and the event listener through their derived type. It is a pain if you really want raw  string as one of the types, though, as char array is more difficult to represent in a pointed to object. But as you are using std::string that isn't an issue.

Comment: ..forgot one point on the list: in `dummyHeavyOperation` you give away a pointer to a local variable that may cause trouble depending on how the client uses that pointer

Comment: "Because data type depends of the event. Sometimes it's a string, sometimes it's raw binary data that should be cast as a struct, and so on"  And that's the bit that's bad design.  Make new callback objects for various types of data because not knowing what's provided in the callback is bad.

Comment: The only reason you'd want to pass arbitrary types to the callback is if your callback knows how to differentiate between them, which it obviously can't since all it got is a `void*`. Use `std::variant` if you must.

Comment: You can also consider something like [Boost.Any](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) / [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) from C++17.

Comment: One common C way is to use opaque struct pointer, look it up. Also, don't use C style cast in C++ (at least not in a case like this), it is asking for grief and difficult bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the many comments! I'm taking notes 
Isn't using `std::any` serves the same purpose that `void*` carries? Should the callback remain generic or should there be an extern callback to implement for each event?

Comment: When your framework calls `notify` how does it know the type of data to pass as the `void*` parameter? Or rather, given that it must know the type, why use a `void*`?

Comment: I suppose this forces the different event callback signatures to be fixed by the framework. In that case I would simply have a different subscriber list for each event type and use strongly typed parameters. I would definitely avoid `void*` and `std::any` if you can. They are useful if the caller supplies their own data to be called back with.

Comment: In fact if you don't store your callbacks in different lists how are you going to know which callback requires which parameters? So they surely will have to each have their own list anyways won't they?

Comment: By removing the type information, all you are doing is forcing the caller to cast the type back to what it was originally. As far as I can see (assuming I understand this correctly) you seem to have gained nothing and put the caller at risk of making a mistake.

Comment: `notify` calls are loosely typed as well, the framework constructs the data internally and forwards the pointer to the notify function. Casting is only done on the client side. So yeah, callbacks, events and types aren't linked in any way as to remain (overly-)generic. I should add as well that the API is delivered as a shared library loaded at run-time. So any compile time coupling (and code generation for that matter, and unless I'm mistaken) is off the table

Comment: But I see your point, callbacks are better strongly typed, and prototypes made public for the client to implement them as needed, did I get that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `void*` is a bad idea. Even more so when the involved types come from you, not the user!

If different events pass different types data to the client, then enforcing type safety is very useful for the user. It prevents things like accidentally passing a callback that expects a string but is called with a double. You want your API to be hard to misuse.

For example, you could do this:

```
template<class T>
RetCallback subscribe(EventEnum& ev, std::function<void(T)> fn) const;
```

Subscribers would spell out the type at call site:

```
auto subscriber = Controller->subscribe<std::string>(EventEnum::FooEvent, callback);
```

You can then check in `subscribe` whether the `EventNum` is ok with that callback signature, or you could even (depending on how many events and callback data types you have) have different `EventNum` *types* for each callback data type so that it is impossible to even call subscribe with mismatching event type and callback signature, like this: https://godbolt.org/g/7xTGiM

`notify` would have to be done in a similar way as `subscribe`.

This way, any mismatch is either impossible (i.e. compiler-enforced) or caught immediately in your API instead of causing unexpected casting failures later on in user code.

Edit: As discussed in the comments, if pinning the user on compile-time event values is ok, you can even template on the event num itself: https://godbolt.org/g/9NYVh3

Comment: Once you make `subscribe` a template, it becomes pointless to use `std::function` as an argument. It may be better to just use a templated argument that can be any callable. `subscribe` can wrap the callable into a `std::function` if it needs to.

Comment: I like this approach but it has one caveat that made me avoid templates from the interface. There's a use-case where the API is loaded at run-time as a shared library, unless I'm mistaken (note: still a newbie) the code that I need for that won't be generated when exporting the symboles because it is not compiled against the main program :(

Comment: @Fluffy You just need to instantiate the function templates with all the types in question. If you know you only ever pass back a string and a double, you can do `template<> subscribe<std::string>(EventEnum&, std::function<void(std::string)>)` and `template<> subscribe<double>(/*...*/)`. This generates the functions regardless of whether the user compiles against your API.

Comment: @user2079303 If you need to wrap the callable in a std::function anyway (which you will definitely have to do from what I can tell) then you might as well document the required callable signature in the API function signature. Also look at the above comments - you can only do the "any callable" thing when you build directly against the API, doing template instantiation in a shared library is impossible for that case. That said, you could probably provide both.

Comment: Okay, so specializing every deduced type is one way, and checking it at run-time avoids any type mismatch. Unless this can also be done at compile-time (static asserts?) I'm not sure why this is a better implementation than providing virtual functions strongly typed for the client to implement?

Comment: (Again, I'm apologizing for any obnoxious mistakes that I might make, still wrapping my mind around all this :D)

Comment: You could include the event num in the template signature: https://godbolt.org/g/9NYVh3. This requires each call to know the event num at compile-time, but if your user doesn't know that then it's hard to pass the right callback - unless you group the events by the required callback signature: https://godbolt.org/g/7xTGiM. Both are extremely type-safe but with different maintenance and usability implications. Pick your poison. :)

Comment: This is very good. Thanks a lot for the effort! I like the template approach a lot. Last thing about this is how I'm storing the callbacks related to registered events. I had a `std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void(void*)>>>` that was convenient with the nasty `void*` signature. What's your take on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169866/discussion-between-max-langhof-and-fluffy).

Comment: A note on why I chose this answer as the solution: it provides a templated approach that is both efficient and type-safe, +compile-time type checking - which I think is dope. And @MaxLanghof help was incredibly comprehensive. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

> C++ API design: is using void* a bad idea?

Yes.

To implement equivalent API, you should use `std::any`, which is a checked version of type erasure. `std::any` is only available in the standard library since the current, C++17 standard version. If you don't have C++17 (or don't want user of the API to depend on C++17), then you can use a non-standard implementation instead.

An alternative is to not erase the argument type at all, but use templates all the way instead. See [Boost Signals](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/signals2.html) for an example of such callback API

Comment: Just note that will immediately make your API incompatible with C and earlier C++ versions

Comment: OP noted elsewhere that he wants to build a shared library, which makes "templating all the way through" a no-go (unless you can also manually instantiate all those templates).

Comment: Yes, I'm adding that to the question, sorry. Thank you for pointing out std::any as an alternative though, if you have a good real life example of `any`, `variant`, and `optional` I'll take it I'm curious what was the reasoning behind this for C++17

Comment: @Fluffy (I rewrote my comment) `any` is like `void*`, except it stores the object rather than points to an object elsewhere. Also, when `any` is converted to an object of wrong type (with `any_cast`), an exception is thrown, which is much better than *undefined behaviour* that you'd get with `void*`.

Comment: Requiring someone using your API to include boost is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

Literally anything is better than `void*`. It's a nasty hack from a time when people were still learning about what people want from the language and how to perform various tasks were only viable with it.

The idea of an opaque pointer is much more maintainable and understandable for an API that is to be used for either C or C++; or even just the one.  It ensures type safety and is easy to read.

In the header file for the API you have:

```
// forward declare a struct called MyThing, but make sure the contents of it aren't available so that we can do anything we want to it in the implementation.
struct MyThing;

// define a class that contains function pointers.  We have a requirement that these function pointers must be valid for the lifetime of them being registered with MyThing.
struct MyThingCallback {
    void (*eventA)(MyThing* sender, const char* someData);
    void (*eventB)(MyThing* sender, int someOtherData);
};

// Some helper functions to do things with MyThing
MyThing* createMyThing();
void deleteMyThing(MyThing*);
void registerCallback(MyThing*, MyThingCallback);

int getSomeProperty(const MyThing*);
void setSomeProperty(MyThing*, int);
```

In the implementation (which includes this file) you then have

```
struct MyThing {
private:
    int property;
    std::vector<MyThingCallback> callbacks;
    // functions are allowed here
};
```

You will note that the API user doesn't need to know anything about `MyThing` because they never access any members of it; they only ever use a pointer to it.  The idea of a `void*`, or even different objects being passed for different events has now been removed and everyone can always be sure that their function will only be used at the right time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I can see you are suggesting having different callbacks for different events, but what does the pointer being opaque has to do with solving the problem?

Comment: @PasserBy for writing an API; anything implementation specific should be hidden; the last thing I would want to do is offer an API that exposes boost!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a basic event system for c++ and I use `void*` for the event handlers, when they callback the object, that fired the event and additional event data.
So firing a common event looks like this:

```
void Invoke(void* sender, void* eventArgs);
```

With an event-handler signature like that, the user of the API can cast the

```
void* sender
```

to the original object, because he always knows what object type fired the event.
At least that is my implementation of an event-system in C++.
You can look it up here: https://github.com/moritzrinow/MindEvent
I also implemented a base class for additional event data 'MindEventArgs', which is inspired by the .NET 'EventArgs'.

So to answer your general question...
I think void* is almost unavoidable for generic API's, that are supposed to be compatible with older versions of C++. :)

Comment: i was almost going to upvote, but i cannot agree at all with "void* is almost unavoidable for generic API's.". Just take a look at the std library which is generic, but so far I didnt encounter a `void*` in there

Comment: Well of course there will always be new fancy things you can use, but I think void* is a legit and common option for generic API's :) Maybe I sounded a little bit stubborn.. sry for that.

Comment: it is not about using new fancy things, but it is about not throwing typesafety out of the window when there are alternatives

Comment: sorry, now its me who sounds stubborn ;) not trying to start a war here, I just encountered some `void*` in apis where it really was not necessary and found it rather annoying

Comment: I think it is a matter of style. I don't really know much about the type safety library of C++, but I'm assuming they use something like Reflection in .NET which is really time consuming. In the end...the dev has to choose wether to write a fast API or a safe API :P

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid void* in the API using template for subscribe and notify functions.

```
enum event {

    fooEvent,

};

type_index p(typeid(void));
void(*pf)(void*);

template<typename T> void Notify(event e, T& data)
{
    auto current_p = type_index(typeid(T));
    if (current_p == p)
        reinterpret_cast<void(*)(T&)>(pf)(data);

}

template<typename T> void Subscribe(event e, void(*f)(T&))
{
    p = type_index(typeid(T));
    pf = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*)>(f);
}
```

Then, in your client code you can write, without using any cast from void:

```
void handler(string& d)
{


}

void test1()
{
    Subscribe(fooEvent, handler);
    ...
    string data = "hello";
    Notify(fooEvent, data);

}
```

Using type_info/type_index you can check at runtime if the parameter type matches. Internally you can continue to use void*.